# How can I build a decreasing lower triangular matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

Do you know if it is possible to get the following triangular matrix

[ N:-1:1; (N-1):-1:0; (N-2):-1:0 0; (N-3):-1:0 0 0; ....] without writing every line with horzcat and without using a loop?
thanks all
Fred

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: sorry it is in matlab

Comment: @Fred you should add it to your tags then

Comment: thanks GottZ, I am knew here, though this forum was only for matlab!

Comment: @Fred This isn't a forum, and it isn't just for MATLAB.  This website is for programming problems and issues of all times.  If you're looking for a MATLAB specific question and answer "forum", check out MATLAB Central: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/ ... however, you're more than welcome to ask your question here too :)

Comment: @ Divakar, @ Luis and @ Beaker thanks a lot!! all the solutions are good for my problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
N = 8;
result = flipud(tril(toeplitz(1:N)));
```

This gives

```
result =    
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0
     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0
     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0
     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
N=10;
M=triu(gallery('circul',N)).'

M =

    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0
    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0
    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0
    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0
   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

Or did you want this:

```
M=fliplr(triu(gallery('circul',N)))
M =

   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0
    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0
    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0
    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0
    5    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
    4    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
    3    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I couldn't really tell from your code sample which direction you wanted this to go.

Answer (score 1):

The power of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) **compels** you!

```
[[N:-1:1]' reshape(repmat([N-1:-1:1]',1,N).*bsxfun(@ge,[1:N-1]',1:N),N,[])]
```

Sample run -

```
>> N = 8;
>> [[N:-1:1]' reshape(repmat([N-1:-1:1]',1,N).*bsxfun(@ge,[1:N-1]',1:N),N,[])]
ans =
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0
     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0
     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0
     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

This is basically inspired by [this another `bsxfun`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212599/3293881) to a very similar question - [Replicate vector and shift each copy by 1 row down without for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209361/replicate-vector-and-shift-each-copy-by-1-row-down-without-for-loop). There you can see similar solutions and related benchmarks, as it seems performance is a concern here.