# Vectorize this loop

Tags: matlab, recursion, vectorization

I have the following loop in MATLAB:

```
n = 20000
rho=0.9;
sigma=[0.1 0.2 0.3];
epsilon = normrnd(0,1, 3, n);
z =  NaN(1,n);
z(1,1) = 0;
for i=2:n
   z(1,i) = rho * z(1,i-1) + sigma* epsilon(:,i);
end
```

I tried vectorizing it by doing:

```
z(1,2:end) = rho * z(1,1:end-1) + sigma * epsilon
```

It didn't work. I understand that the problem is that this bit: `z(1,2:end) = rho * z(1,1:end-1)` is not recursive.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The problem is that each element depends on the previous element, hence the requirement of a loop. Perhaps `bsxfun` can solve it, but for recursive functions I'd always use a loop.

Comment: This is very tough to vectorize, besides the for loop is very fast. On my system the example takes less than 0.02s. Unless your actual problem is much larger, I don't think it's worth the time.

Comment: Why do you want to vectorise it?

Comment: Write a Mex-file. If you don't know how to, then it will be a good addition to your skill set. If you know, then this shouldn't take more than half an hour.

Comment: Wow! Way to many answers, all of them useful! Not sure which to accept.
@Daniel, my program is much much larger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a post apocalyptic world filled with **`crazy fast parallel processors and almost-free memory latency machines`**, where vectorizing tools like `bsxfun` and `matrix multiplication` could easily spawn across 20,000 cores, one *lost soul* desperately trying to vectorize such a problem could venture into something like this -

```
parte1 = tril(rho.^(bsxfun(@minus,(0:n-2)',0:n-2)));
parte2 = sigma*epsilon(:,2:end);
z = [0 parte2*parte1.']
```

In all seriousness, it's not supposed to be memory-efficient and thus, isn't likely to be fast .. *now*, but is meant to demonstrate a way to trace the recursion and apply it for a vectorized solution.

Comment: You could use `parte1 = tril(rho.^[0:n-2]'*rho.^(0:-1:-n+2));` to avoid the n^2 calculations of a power, which is the slowest part of the code.

Comment: Or `parte1 = toeplitz(rho.^[0:n-2],[1,zeros(1,n-2)]);`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! Those could be used and also there's a similar question to create a matrix like `parte1` in [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209361/replicate-vector-and-shift-each-copy-by-1-row-down-without-for-loop). This post was meant more as a guide to trace recursions like these. For performance, the partially vectorized approach in your solution would be the go-to solution.

Answer (score 4):

Partially vectorizing the code lowered the execution time for your example form 0.015s to 0.0005s on my system. I simply pre-calculated `sigma* epsilon(:,i)` using a single matrix multiplication:

```
n = 20000
rho=0.9;
sigma=[0.1 0.2 0.3];
epsilon = normrnd(0,1, 3, n);
se=sigma*epsilon;
z =  NaN(1,n);
z(1,1) = 0;
for i=2:n
   z(1,i) = rho * z(1,i-1) + se(i);
end
```

Comment: I think you mean `se(:,i)`?

Comment: Oh ok. sigma is `1x3`, I missed that.

Comment: Funny enough on my machine the original code tales 0.04 seconds whereas your alternative takes 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you re-write this particular program in a way that does not use recursion you cannot vectorize it.

It is very hard to have vectorized calculations involving recursion because most of the time you cannot have a closed form expression for the function you try to solve (effectively at any given time-point you do not a finite number of operations; and even if you do have a finite number that will grow exponentially).

I think you might want to consider re-writing your function using [filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html). It is specifically designed for such relations.

EDIT:

As mentioned, what you describe is an elementary filter. Assuming the same setting as @Daniel you simply have:

```
...
epsilon = normrnd(0,1, 3, n);
se=sigma*epsilon;

a = [1 -rho];
b = 1; 
z = filter(b, a, [0  se(2:n)] );
```

I believe that you will consistently find this to be the faster of the three solutions proposed. To me it also appears to be the most natural as your problem statement describes a filtering algorithm.