# Replacing iteration in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion, vectorization

I'm attempting to rewrite the following routine (a, b, c, d, and e are all arrays):

```
def generate_a(b, c, e):
    a = np.zeros_like(b)
    d = np.zeros_like(b)
    for i in range(a.size):
        a[i] = (b[i] / c[i]) + d[i-1]
        d[i] = a[i] * e[i]
    return a
```

without using the 'for' loop, since the routine needs to be run millions of times.  This one's a little trick since the value of any given cell in d depends on the result calculated for the cell in a, which in turn depends on the last value calculated for d. Any ideas on how this could be done without iteration?

Comment: for element `a[0]`, what value of `d` is expected to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a[i]` depends on `d[i-1]` and `d[i-1]` depends on `a[i-1]`, `a[i]` also depends on `a[0], a[1], ... a[i-1]` and you won't be able to parallelize the computation as it stands. You'll need to either accept that loop or figure out a closed form way to do your computation.

Comment: the closed form is computable

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by this [`solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443960/3293881), this is a post to show that **recursions are `vectorizable`**, if the recursions could be *traced*. As stated in the linked solution, again this is not supposed to be fast *as of now*, but with parallel processors to leverage, this approach could be given a shot. So, please take this post as a guidance on how recursions could be traced and vectorized. Here's the implementation -

```
def generate_a_vectorized(b, c, e):

    K = (b/c)*e
    N = e.size

    mask = np.linspace(N,1,N,dtype=int)[:,None] <= np.arange(N)

    Pn = np.tile(e[None],(N,1))
    Pn[mask] = 1
    En = Pn[:,::-1].cumprod(1)[:,::-1]
    En[mask] = 0
    An = np.append(0,K[:-1])

    d_out = En.dot(An)[::-1] + K
    return (b/c) + np.append(0,d_out[:-1])
```

Sample run & verify outputs -

```
In [279]: M = 50
     ...: b = np.random.rand(M)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(M)
     ...: e = np.random.rand(M)
     ...: 

In [280]: np.allclose(generate_a(b, c, e),generate_a_vectorized(b, c, e))
Out[280]: True

In [281]: %timeit generate_a(b,c,e)
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.4 µs per loop

In [282]: %timeit generate_a_vectorized(b,c,e)
10000 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and lambda.

Try:

```
import numpy as np

def func(i,l):
    l[0][i] = (l[1][i] / l[2][i]) + l[3][i-1]
    l[3][i] = l[0][i] * l[4][i]

    return l[0][i]

def generate_a(b, c, e):
    a = np.zeros_like(b)
    d = np.zeros_like(b)

    a = map(lambda i:func(i,[a, b, c, d, e]), xrange(a.size))

    return a

print generate_a([5, 6, 7],[1,2,3],[8,9,12])
```

Comment: This is more elegant but there's not much of a time savings since the map function is still iterative.

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea with Mathematica (since `b[i]/c[i]` is independant from the computation, I call it `bc[i]` below):

```
Wolfram Language (Raspberry Pi Pilot Release)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research
Information & help: wolfram.com/raspi

In[1]:= RSolve[ { a[i]==bc[i] + a[i-1]*e[i-1], a[-1]==0 }, a[i], i]                    

Out[1]= {{a[i] -> 

>      Product[e[K[1]], {K[1], 1, -1 + i}] 

                      bc[1 + K[2]]
>       Sum[---------------------------------, {K[2], -1, -1 + i}]}}
            Product[e[K[1]], {K[1], 1, K[2]}]
```

As Randy C tolt it previously, unless previous computation would have resulted in something simpler, I strongly doubt you can get better than what you already have. *You can get nicer code but probably no more efficient code.*