# Reshaping vector in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

I am trying to implement [BlockLMS](http://cwww.ee.nctu.edu.tw/course/asp/ASP06.pdf) with a single for loop in MATLAB. For this purpose, given a vector **u**, I am trying to create a table of the form

```
U = [u(k)     u(k+1)     u(k+2)  ...    u(k+n)
     u(k-1)   u(k)       ...     ...    u(k+n-1)
     ...      ...        ...     ...    ...
     u(k-n)   u(k-n+1)   ...     ...    u(k)]
```

where **n** is a constant and **k** is a variable which changes with each for loop, assuming `k > n` at all times. What I have accomplished so far is this:

```
index = meshgrid(0:-1:1-n)' + meshgrid(1:n);
for i = 2:q
    % calculate k
    U = u(k + index);
    % rest of code goes here
end
```

which, although it works, is sadly very slow and does not suit my needs. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this result?

Comment: looks like you just need a Toeplitz matrix, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That operation has a lot of replications. So, to exploit that very nature, here's one approach using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and a little help from [`bsxfun's`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) masking capability -

```
mask = bsxfun(@ge,(1:2*n+1)',n+1:-1:1) & bsxfun(@ge,(2*n+1:-1:1)',1:n+1)
sliced_u = u(k+n:-1:k-n)
repvals = repmat(sliced_u(:),1,n+1)
out = reshape(repvals(mask),n+1,[])
```

The way one could describe this approach would be to see the desired output's columns as one place shifted up as we traverse to the right when a columnar version of the input `u` is replicated along the columns. The rest of the work is to offset the one place shifting along the columns, which is done with the `bsxfun`'s masking to cutoff the upper and lower triangular regions to give us the final output.

**Performance :** This idea has been exploited before for a similar problem in [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212599/3293881) and I expect similar performance numbers here.

---

As another approach and thinking straight-forward, one could just use `bsxfun` to get the 2D indices and then index into `u` for the final output, like so -

```
out = u(bsxfun(@plus,(k:-1:k-n)',0:n))
```

Comment: Although I didn't expect that, your second and straightforward approach is better. What's even better, though, is to create a constant index matrix outside the `for loop`, sample the vector `u` for the values that are needed for each loop and then construct the matrix by indexing the sampled vector. Since your post was what helped me achieve this result, I'm accepting this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @naltipar Glad to hear that this was helpful! Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the one-liner built in `toeplitz`

```
 toeplitz(20:-1:15,20:25)

ans =

20    21    22    23    24    25
19    20    21    22    23    24
18    19    20    21    22    23
17    18    19    20    21    22
16    17    18    19    20    21
15    16    17    18    19    20
```

Or, in a more generic way:

```
f = @(k,n)toeplitz(k:-1:k-n,k:k+n)
```

and then you can just write `U=u(f(k,n))` to get the generic form in the question.
But check if that is indeed faster than your for loop.

EDIT: the inner machinery of `toeplitz` is `bsxfun`, so I guess unless you realize it in lower level c\fortran, this is as good as it gets. Check `edit toeplitz` and see how it is implemented...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After sampling in order to keep only each loop's needed values, using toeplitz certainly makes the loop run faster.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```matlab
k = 20;     % Example k
n = 5;      % Example n < k

u = 1:50;   % Example vector

[x, y] = meshgrid(0:n,k:-1:k-n);
U = u(x+y)   % Use x+y as index
U =

   20   21   22   23   24   25
   19   20   21   22   23   24
   18   19   20   21   22   23
   17   18   19   20   21   22
   16   17   18   19   20   21
   15   16   17   18   19   20
```

As you can see, the top left corner is element number `k`, the top right is element number `k+n`, the bottom left is `k-n` and the bottom right is element `k`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This implementation is fairly identical to mine, although yours is more elegantly written and sadly gives no boost to the loop.