# how to create the matrix with the shifted version of the signal samples in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have vector of size 25001x1 which represent one of my signal samples and i want to create the matrix such way that  first column of the matrix is my vector or signal and the rest of  each column is shifted version of the the original signal or vector.which i accomplish with following way(the vector of 10x1 is consider for the understanding purpose) by adding zeros.

```
 y=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 ]';

 A=zeros(10,10);

 for i=1:length(y)
 A(:,i)=y;
 y=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 ]';
 y=[zeros(1,(i))';y(1:end-(i))];

 end
```

which result in following

```
>> A

 A =

 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0     0
 7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0     0
 8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0     0
 9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1     0
10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

Now when i want to shift more than one element or wanted to add more than one zero i did the following

```
y=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11 ]';

A=zeros(11,11);

for i=1:length(y)
A(:,i)=y;
y=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11  ]';
y=[zeros(1,(i*2))';y(1:end-(i*2))];
if (i>=(length(y)/2))
    break;
end 


end
```

which results in the following

```
>> A

A =

 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 4     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6     4     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 7     5     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8     6     4     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9     7     5     3     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
10     8     6     4     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
11     9     7     5     3     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Is there any generalize method to do same thing and that too without using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is answered [in this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209361/replicate-vector-and-shift-each-copy-by-1-row-down-without-for-loop). The fastest method there (not the accepted answer) is as follows:

```matlab
N = numel(A);
val = repmat([A(:);0],1,N).*bsxfun(@le,[1:N+1]',[N:-1:1]);
out = reshape(val(1:N*N),N,N);
```

For MATLAB R2016b and newer we can modernize that:

```matlab
N = numel(A);
val = repmat([A(:);0],1,N) .* ((1:N+1).' <= (N:-1:1));
out = reshape(val(1:N*N),N,N);
```

(I simply replaced `bsxfun(@le,x,y)` with `x<=y`, since a few years ago there is no longer a need to use `bsxfun` in these cases. I also removed redundant concatenation operators `[]`, and replaced `'` with `.'`, which is more correct for this use.)

For the second part of your question, we need to generalize the code above in a non-trivial manner. The following code is the result of that:

```matlab
N = numel(A);
step = 2;          % Set this to however many zeros you want to add each column
indx = N:-step:1;
M = numel(indx);
val = (1:N+step).' <= indx; % use bsxfun(@le, (1:N+step).',indx) instead for older MATLAB
val = repmat([A(:);zeros(step,1)],1,M).* val;
out = reshape(val(1:N*M),N,[]);
```

I've replaced `N:-1:1` with `N:-step:1`, this is the main change. I also needed to add `step` zeros to `A`, instead of only one (this is the `[A(:);zeros(step,1)]`, where before it was `[A(:);0]`). And I adjusted sizes everywhere to account for the smaller output array.

Note that this does not produce any of the empty (all-zero) columns. To add those, it is simplest to do:

```matlab
out2 = zeros(N,N);
out2(:,1:size(out,2)) = out;
```

Comment: `(1:N+1).' <= (N:-1:1)`  is showing the error of **Error using  <= 
Matrix dimensions must agree.**

Comment: @ Cris Luengo as my first comment suggest that the changes you made instead of using `bsxfun(@le,x,y)` is not working in both the code. second code instead of logical operator i use `bsxfun(@le,x,y)` and one more slight  change i made in the code `val = repmat([A(:);zeros(step,1)],1,M).* (val');` then it works fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Anil: If you have an older version of MATLAB, then you need to keep using `bsxfun`. I assumed you were current with your version, apologies. The second change you made I don’t understand. If you somehow need that, it means you generated `val ` in the wrong orientation. Try to fix the previous line instead, transposing a matrix is expensive.

Comment: yes, you are correct, your code is perfectly fine with Matlab2017.thanks a lot once again.