# How to form the matrix of logical '1' and '0' using two vectors and logical operators in r?

Tags: r, matlab

Here is Matlab code to form the matrix of logical values of '0' and '1'

```
 A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ];
 N = numel(A);
 step = 2;    % Set this to however many zeros you want to add each column
 index = N:-step:1;
 val = (1:N+step).' <= index;
```

Which result in

```
 val=

 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

How to do same task in r ,particularly `val = (1:N+step).' <= index`this step?

Comment: So if this would be a function in R, what exactly would be the input? I'm not sure how to interpret your variables. It would be better if you just rewrote the question to talk about the problem you are trying to solve rather than a question about translating code from one language to another (which is generally considered to be off-topic).

Comment: @MrFlick sorry I forget to add the initial vector A.

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
i <- seq_len(ncol(m1))
sapply(rev(i), function(.i) {
         m1[,.i][sequence(.i *2)] <- 1
         m1[,.i]
   })
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [6,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [7,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [9,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

---

Or vectorize it

```
i1 <- rep(i,  rev(2*i))
m1[cbind(ave(i1, i1, FUN = seq_along), i1)] <- 1
m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [6,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [7,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [9,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

---

Or another option without creating a `matrix` beforehand

```
n <- 5
i1 <- seq(10, 2, by = -2)
r1 <- c(rbind(i1, rev(i1)))
matrix(rep(rep(c(1, 0), n), r1), ncol = n)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [6,]    1    1    1    0    0
# [7,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    0    0    0
# [9,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(0, 12, 5)
```

Comment: @markus Thank you for spotting that.  I may have reassigned `m1`.  Will change it

Comment: thanks for your help,but may you make it more general for step size as the following link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839199/how-to-create-the-matrix-with-the-shifted-version-of-the-signal-samples-in-matla) will tell you what exactly i want