# how to create the matrix with the shifted version of signal samaples vector in r?

Tags: r

This question I already asked for Matlab and I got the required answer.here is the link for that question-[how to create the matrix with the shifted version of the signal samples in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839199/how-to-create-the-matrix-with-the-shifted-version-of-the-signal-samples-in-matla).
As I am working on my data both in Matlab and r ,I am trying to developed same code for r.In that attempt I asked the following question the link given-[How to form the matrix of logical '1' and '0' using two vectors and logical operators in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909505/how-to-form-the-matrix-of-logical-1-and-0-using-two-vectors-and-logical-oper.So) now using answer given(not yet accepted) to my second question I developed the following r code.

```
library("pracma")
x=c(1:10)
N=numel(x)
step=2
index=seq(N,1,by=-step)
M=numel(index)
r1 <- c(rbind((index), rev(index)))
val<-matrix(rep(rep(c(1, 0), M), r1), ncol = M)
val1=val*matrix(repmat(c(x,matrix(0,1,step)),1,M),12,M)
out=matrix(val1[1:(N*M)],N,M)
```

which result in the

```
 > out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    1    0    0    0
[4,]    4    2    0    0    0
[5,]    5    3    1    0    0
[6,]    6    4    2    0    0
[7,]    7    5    3    1    0
[8,]    8    6    4    2    0
[9,]    9    7    5    3    1
[10,]   10    8    6    4    2
```

but as I change the step size it won't work, how can i make this code more generalize for step size?

Comment: Write a function with step as an argument?

Comment: I think you may need `val[!!val] <- sequence(colSums(val)); val <- val[x,]` and to keep it in the reverse, `apply(val, 2, rev)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NelsonGon mentioned in the comments, creating a function with slight modification of the code would help

```
f1 <- function(v, step) {

    N <- pracma::numel(v)
    index <- seq(N,1,by=-step)
    M <- pracma::numel(index)
    r1 <- c(rbind((index), rev(index)))
    val <- matrix(rep(rep(c(1, 0), M), r1), ncol = M)
    val[!!val] <- sequence(colSums(val))
    apply(val[x,], 2, function(x) x[order(x != 0)])
}
```

-testing

```
f1(1:10, 2)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    2    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    4    2    0    0    0
# [5,]    5    3    1    0    0
# [6,]    6    4    2    0    0
# [7,]    7    5    3    1    0
# [8,]    8    6    4    2    0
# [9,]    9    7    5    3    1
#[10,]   10    8    6    4    2

f1(1:10, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    2    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    0    0
# [4,]    4    1    0    0
# [5,]    5    2    0    0
# [6,]    6    3    0    0
# [7,]    7    4    1    0
# [8,]    8    5    2    0
# [9,]    9    6    3    0
#[10,]   10    7    4    1
```

Note: If the intention is to keep columns with only 0's as well, it can be done in the function

```
f1(1:10, 4)
#        [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    2    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    0
# [4,]    4    0    0
# [5,]    5    1    0
# [6,]    6    2    0
# [7,]    7    3    0
# [8,]    8    4    0
# [9,]    9    5    1
#[10,]   10    6    2

f1(1:10, 5)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    2    0
# [3,]    3    0
# [4,]    4    0
# [5,]    5    0
# [6,]    6    1
# [7,]    7    2
# [8,]    8    3
# [9,]    9    4
#[10,]   10    5
```

Comment: one issue is that i assume that the function will work even when the vector x has value of double or float type.But if you consider a x vector of double or float type it will generate the unusual result.

Comment: @AnilSarode  I haven't tested on that.  The float could have impact on the `seq`

Comment: Do you know any remedy ?